# Ionic HTTP POST reply net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: http, ionic-framework

My Ionic Info is below:

```
cli packages: (C:\Windows\System32\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : not installed
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11
Cordova Platforms  : android 7.0.0 browser 5.0.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.3
npm               : 6.3.0
OS                : Windows 7
```

Hi, I have built an app and it is working fine on the browser. But on the mobile I am getting this error, screenshot is below.

[image: ERROR]

Below is the reply on the browser which is working fine.

[image: reply]

I have restarted my phone.
I have cleared the app memory.
My config.xml is below.

[image: config.xml]

The reply from the server is below.

> **"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nContent-Length: 10\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: \r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Headers: \r\n\r\n" + ipStr + “”;

As you can see, I have the Access Control Allow Origin there also.
Please help as I can't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: could you provide the typescript code from the service where you make the http post? Maybe it could help

Comment: I have used both native and   angular http. With the angular the error is in my question as you saw.

With native error is below.

Status 0, host could not be resolved.

    this.httpNative.setHeader("http://page.local:80/", "Content-Type", "text/plain");

    this.httpNative.get('http://page.local:80/test', {}, JSON.stringify(headers))
      .then(data => {console.log(data);  }).catch(error => {     console.log(error);  });

    this.http.get("http://uniqair.local:80/", {}).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

Comment: ok and did you get somthing comming from the catch(error => { console.log(error ??

Comment: Hi, yes: Status 0, host could not be resolved.

Comment: New error: {status: -1, error: "There was an error with the request: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: page.local"}

Comment: By the way, I have a mDNS server running. If I give the post to the IP of the server then the post goes fine. But the idea is to give the post to a local address which returns the IP of the device/server.

Comment: Seems like the host is unreachable, did you tried to ping the ip or open with the browser?

Comment: Hi, Yes the Ping from PC works. The Post from postman works. The page.local can be accessed from PC browser. The Ionic serve on the browser works. On Android neither teh app nor the browser request works. Did yo understand teh basic idea as to why im doing it? The purpose is to ping a local address which in turn replies the IP of the wifi module. After which all the communication through the IP will work which is working here too. But the local address is the issue.

Comment: I even tried to use Ping plugin, i tried to use different discovery plugins also making mobile either client or server but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: @EmileCantero do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are yo on a personnal network or a company network? I think it a port issue

Comment: I am on a company network. But why does from my PC i can access it?

Comment: Looks like the host port you tried to reach is closed

Comment: But I can reach it using POSTMAN or the browser on the laptop, just on on the mobile. I guess Android is not allowing me to access local domain.

Comment: Did you try postman with the same port as Android? Even in your hhtp service you can specify the port..

Comment: Hi, yes I tried with the same port. Is there any other way to do the discovery of the device ?